# square-summable sequence with weights

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have got the following question.

Consider the measure space $(X, \mathbb{B}, \lambda)$, where $X$ is an infinite countable set $X= \{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots \}$, $\mathbb{B}$ is a sigma algebra, and $\lambda$ is a measure, such that $\lambda(x_{i}) = w_{i}$, with $w_{i} > 0$. Next, consider the space of all real-valued measurable functions on $X$, which are square integrable with respect to the measure $\lambda$. 
$$
\int_{X}[f(x)]^{2}\lambda(dx) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[f(x_{i})]^{2}w_{i} < \infty.
$$

Then the space of those functions on $X$ is a Hilbert space with the inner product $(f,g) = \int_{X}f(x)g(x)\lambda(dx)$.

My question: is it correct, that the space of corresponding square summable with weights $\bf{w}$ sequences, i.e $\sum_{i}y_{i}^{2}w_{i} < \infty$ is a Hilbert space and which requirements must be imposed on the weights $\bf{w}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered the first part of your question. Since $X$ is countable, functions from $X$ are just sequences themselves. And the inner product you put on $X$ is the same that would be put on sequences.

No condition needs to be put on the weights. You just let the underlying set be the set of all sequences that are square summable with respect to those weights.